# An alternative to org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value which is not Spring based

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations

I am a Spring user and I'm quite fond of things like `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value` and dependency injection.

Unfortunately, for the project I'm working on, a requirement is not to use Spring. Sure, I can write a stupid class that loads the properties and has the respective getter methods for these properties. What I'm wondering about is whether there is an alternative more elegant and lightweight package which can inject these values from properties files into my variables for me. Something with nifty annotations like the above-mentioned.

I basically have to avoid the whole complexity of the Spring/Guice frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's [Commons-Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/user_guide.html), but it's nowhere near as easy as annotating a bean field. If it's really just a handful of keys, you may be best off just hand-coding something. Just make sure you recognize when it's getting out of hand and then use a framework after all.

Comment: If you're launching a stand-alone app, `System.getProperty(String,String)` covers the simplest configuration requirements just fine. If it's a servlet, use `init-param`s.

Comment: @BarendGarvelink: Look, if I wanted to use System.getProperty, I wouldn't be asking for an annotated class. I have properties files. Passing cmd line arguments is seriously inconvenient.
The servlet suggestion is also not what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, you never did mention whether it's a servlet app or a stand-alone app, so I had to cover both bases. There's not much wiggle room between nothing at all and "simpler than Guice", so I offered getProperty and init-params as the simplest thing that could possibly work. Anyway, good luck. If you find (or create & open-source) anything useful, please post it as an answer your own question for the benefit of others.

Comment: So, being the lazy-ass bastard that I am, and being the kind of guy who can't stand writing boring code over and over, I knocked this thing up. I will set up a project in google code or github and put the code there. It basically injects the values for the properties via an annotation and an injector class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question, as I ended up knocking up the code myself and putting it up on github.

So, if anybody would ever need something like this, you can have a look at:

https://github.com/carlspring/properties-injector

I will try an push it to Maven Central as it's a Maven project.